# Get report output in PDF fromat via Acumatica REST API

Tags: rest, pdf, acumatica

Is it possible to get PDF output of the report generated as a result of the action invoked for the particular screen via `REST API`?

For instance, we want to provide users of the external application with the ability to execute "Print Invoice/Memo Form" action for a particular Invoice in the AR Invoice screen in *Acumatica*. They expect to get Invoice Form in PDF format as the result of the call.

If there is no such option, maybe there is a way to generate a link which will bring the user to the Invoice form report executed with the specified set of parameters values. *Acumatica* login information and report parameters values are stored in the external application.

Thank you!

Comment: FYI from what I can tell as of 2020 R2 this is still not available using the Contract-Based REST API (without customization), but is available using the Screen-Based SOAP API.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer yes, long answer....not easily.

To implement the functionality you request the following steps must be taken.

First create an action on the AR Invoice screen that will generate a report, save and attach it to the document.

```
public class ARInvoiceEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
{
    public PXAction<ARInvoice> exportReport;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Export Report")]
    [PXButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable ExportReport(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        //Report Paramenters
        Dictionary<String, String> parameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        parameters["ARInvoice.DocType"] = Base.Document.Current.DocType;
        parameters["ARInvoice.RefNbr"] = Base.Document.Current.RefNbr;

        //Report Processing
        PX.Reports.Controls.Report _report = PXReportTools.LoadReport("AR641000", null);
        PXReportTools.InitReportParameters(_report, parameters,
                SettingsProvider.Instance.Default);
        ReportNode reportNode = ReportProcessor.ProcessReport(_report);

        //Generation PDF
        byte[] data = PX.Reports.Mail.Message.GenerateReport(reportNode,
        ReportProcessor.FilterPdf).First();

        PX.SM.FileInfo file = new PX.SM.FileInfo(reportNode.ExportFileName + ".pdf", null, data);

        UploadFileMaintenance graph = new UploadFileMaintenance();
        graph.SaveFile(file);
        PXNoteAttribute.AttachFile(Base.Document.Cache, Base.Document.Current, file);

        return adapter.Get();
    }
}
```

Second you will have to create a method utilizing the Contract API to find the Invoice, trigger the action and then retrieve the file attached to the document.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AcumaticaProcessor processor = new AcumaticaProcessor();
        processor.Login();
        File[] result = processor.RetrieveReport("Invoice", "001007");
    }
}

public class AcumaticaProcessor
{
    DefaultSoapClient client = new DefaultSoapClient();

    public void Login()
    {
        client.Login("Username", "Password", "Company", "Branch", null);
    }

    public File[] RetrieveReport(string docType, string refNbr)
    {
        ARInvoice invoiceToFind = new ARInvoice()
        {
            Type = new StringSearch() { Value = docType },
            ReferenceNbr = new StringSearch() { Value = refNbr }
        };
        invoiceToFind = client.Get(invoiceToFind) as ARInvoice;

        InvokeResult result = client.Invoke(invoiceToFind, new ExportReport());


        return client.GetFiles(invoiceToFind) as File[];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Joshua. Thank you for the idea! It seems that there is no way to achieve this using the out-of-the-box functionality and endpoint.

Comment: It requires extending the endpoint to add the custom action. This method is sound.