# How do we attach report PDF/Excel file when i click on custom action on Sales order screen using Acumatica code

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We have a requirement is to create new action on sales order screen and when we click on that custom action we are opening email activity screen to send an email in that email we want to attach a report PDF/Excel file without clicking report action button separately, but it should get happen when we click on custom action button through code.

Is this possible to attach the report file when we click on custom action button instead of report action.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319158/get-report-output-in-pdf-fromat-via-acumatica-rest-api

I think it contains a relevant example that you can also use

Comment: Hi Dimtri , is it possible to attach a report pdf without using API call

Comment: Sure, just use the code from the answer and invoke it from UI

Answer (score 3):

This is possible using `PXReportTools` and `PX.SM.FileInfo` in your custom action. As *Dmitrii Naumov* pointed out in the comments, [the method posted by *Joshua Van Hoesen*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49325327/1748460) does this, you just need to set the report you need and set the parameters it expects.

Here is the required code for anyone that finds this question:

```cs
public class ARInvoiceEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
{
    public PXAction<ARInvoice> attachReport;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Attach Report")]
    [PXButton]
    public virtual IEnumerable AttachReport(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        //Report Paramenters
        Dictionary<String, String> parameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        parameters["ARInvoice.DocType"] = Base.Document.Current.DocType;
        parameters["ARInvoice.RefNbr"] = Base.Document.Current.RefNbr;

        //Report Processing
        PX.Reports.Controls.Report _report = PXReportTools.LoadReport("AR641000", null);
        PXReportTools.InitReportParameters(_report, parameters,
                SettingsProvider.Instance.Default);
        ReportNode reportNode = ReportProcessor.ProcessReport(_report);

        //Generation PDF
        byte[] data = PX.Reports.Mail.Message.GenerateReport(reportNode,
        ReportProcessor.FilterPdf).First();

        PX.SM.FileInfo file = new PX.SM.FileInfo(reportNode.ExportFileName + ".pdf", null, data);

        UploadFileMaintenance graph = new UploadFileMaintenance();
        graph.SaveFile(file);
        PXNoteAttribute.AttachFile(Base.Document.Cache, Base.Document.Current, file);

        return adapter.Get();
    }
}
```